# Yii2 findBySql: How to specify $params?

Tags: yii2

Yii2 provides ActiveRecord::findBySql für raw SQL queries:

[public static yii\db\ActiveQuery findBySql ( $sql, $params = [] )](http://public%20static%20yii%5Cdb%5CActiveQuery%20findBySql%20(%20$sql,%20$params%20=%20[]%20))

Since there is no hint in the documentation: How to specify `$params`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The reason there isn't any docs about the params passed to the `findBySql()` method is because the method returns the instance of `ActiveQuery` and if you see the last line of this method in `yii\db\ActiveRecord.php` it sets the `$params` via `$query->params($params)`, means the `yii\db\ActiveQuery` function `params($params)` which defines the [$params](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#$params-detail) as

> `$params` list of query parameter values indexed by parameter
>   placeholders. For example, `[':name' => 'Dan', ':age' => 31]`.

---

I guess you should try the following way if lets say you have a table with name product

```
+----+-----------------+------------+--------+
| id | name            | is_deleted | price  |
+----+-----------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | shugal          |          1 |  65.00 |
|  2 | spoon           |          1 |  55.00 |
|  4 | kettle          |          1 |  15.00 |
|  5 | spoon           |          0 |  15.00 |
|  6 | plates          |          0 | 105.00 |
|  7 | dishes          |          0 |  15.00 |
|  8 | forks           |          0 |  15.00 |
| 10 | pressure cooker |          0 | 203.00 |
| 16 | shugal          |          1 |  65.00 |
| 17 | something       |          0 |  25.00 |
| 25 | multi product   |          0 |   0.00 |
| 66 | pans            |          0 |  15.00 |
+----+-----------------+------------+--------+
```

using the following code you can select all the products that are deleted using params

```
$q = Product::findBySql(
    "SELECT * FROM product where is_deleted=:deleted",
    [':deleted' => 1]
)->all();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @WeSee look into the **update** section in the answer. hope it helps.